# How to add a new column into a dataframe based on rows of an other dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

I have two Dataframes :

DF1(That i've just resampled):

```
 Mi_pollution.head():



   Sensor_ID     Time_Instant    Measurement
0    10273   2013-11-01 00:00:00    46
1    10273   2013-11-01 01:00:00    51
2    10273   2013-11-01 02:00:00    39
3    10273   2013-11-01 03:00:00    30
4    10273   2013-11-01 04:00:00    37
```

And I have the DF2 :

```
Pollutants.head():

    Sensor_ID     Sensor_Street_Name    Sensor_Lat  Sensor_Long  Sensor_Type   UOM   Time_Instant
 0  20020   Milano -via Carlo Pascal    45.478452   9.235016     Ammonia       µg/m   YYYY/MM/DD
 1  17127   Milano - viale Marche       45.496067   9.193023     Benzene       µg/m   YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI
 2  17126   Milano -via Carlo Pascal    45.478452   9.235016     Benzene       µg/m   YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI
 3  6057    Milano - via Senato         45.470780   9.197180     Benzene       µg/m   YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI
 4  6062    Milano - P.zza Zavattari    45.476089   9.143509     Benzene       µg/m   YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI
```

And What I'm trying to to do , is to create new columns based on the pollutants and add them to DF1 and assign each measurement based on the Sensor , like This:

```
 Sensor_ID    Time_Instant      Ammonia    Benzene   Nitrogene  …...
0   20020   2013-12-01 00:00:00   4.8       Nan       Nan
1   20020   2013-12-01 01:00:00   5.3       Nan       Nan
2   20020   2013-12-01 02:00:00   3.0       Nan       Nan
.
.
56  14330   2013-11-01 00:00:00   Nan      6.3        Nan
57  14330   2013-11-01 01:00:00   Nan      5.3        Nan
.
.
```

Any Suggestion Would be much appreciated , Thank U all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're joining on `Sensor_ID` (there aren't any common `Sensor_IDs` between the two dataframes in the small example you gave), you could merge the dfs on `Sensor_ID` (and possibly `Time_Instant`?).

Then you can use `pivot_table` to transpose the row values (`Sensor_Type`) to column headings, then fill in the row values with `Measurement`.

For example:
`df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Sensor_ID', how='left')\
                      .pivot_table(index=['Sensor_ID','Sensor_Street_Name','Other columns'], 
                                   values='Measurement', 
                                   columns='Sensor_Type')\
                      .reset_index()`

Comment: Thank's , it's Actually a good idea , but i do have an Error when i try to run the code above , i get this Error:               'No numeric types to aggregate'

Comment: If that's the case, `Measurement` might be read in as an `object` instead of `integer` or `float`. Try `df1['Measurement'] = df1['Measurement'].astype(float)`

Comment: Indeed , that was the issue , one More thing though , after Trying to merge on Time_Instant ( since i want every measurement for every sensor on every Hour) I got an empty Dataframe !!

Comment: I wouldn't merge on `Time_Instant` if that's the case, and I would add `Time_Instant_x` (`Time_Instant` from `df1`) to the list of `indexes` in the `pivot_table` statement

Comment: I tried this:                                                                            Time_Instant_X = df1['Time_Instant']  and then added it to the list of indexes and got this Error : KeyError: 'Time_Instant_X'

Comment: If you have `Time_Instant` in both dataframes, when you merge them, it will bring over both columns, but the column from `df1` will be named `Time_Instant_x` and the column from `df2` will be renamed `Time_Instant_y`. If `Time_Instant` isn't in `df2`, then just add `Time_Instant` to the list of indexes.

Comment: So , I should drop the Time_Instant column in the second dataframe and since i'll be having only one Time_Instant column (the one of df1) and add it the list of indexes.

Comment: Indeed , by droping it , it worked perfecly , Thank's Again for Everything.